# Previous and next value datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've create a datagridview that show me my data. Then I should click on a row and I'd like to show a form where I can update my values.
Is it possible go to the previous/next element of the datagridview in another form? Because I'd like to create two buttons that allow me to scan the whole table and update each value.

Can you help me, please? I really don't know where to start

**EDIT:** This is the code to show my data

```
public static string StringaConnessione = "Data Source=localhost;Database=db;userid=root;password='';";
    public static MySqlConnection Connessione = new MySqlConnection(StringaConnessione);

void MostraBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connessione.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA=new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Acquisti",Connessione);
        DataTable DATA= new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(DATA);
        dataGridView1.DataSource=DATA; 
        Connessione.Close();
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: @Bas I wrote only the code to show data. I don't know what to write after that. I have edited my post